# Ploting Graphs on Web using Flask

Tags: python, flask, plotly, backend, web-deployment

I am having multiple Plotly graphs in my python notebook and I want to plot the same on Web to deploy. I am using FLASK as backend.
Example:

```
fig = px.line(grouped, x="Diagnosed date", y="tot_confirmed", title="Day Wise Cases")
```

I want to keep the graphs responsive as they are in my python notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Plotting dynamically in a DOM is not the intent of MatPlotLib, while there [are packages](https://mpld3.github.io/quickstart.html) that will plot a MatPlotLib object into a DOM, they are static images, or generally less use friendly than MatPlotLib. What *is* designed for this exact use-case though, is [Plotly.js](https://plotly.com/python/) which has a python module you can use with Flask.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/). You have the ability of updating the graphs in real time too.